Composite Fiber Board Siding
I had to remove some rotten siding because some trim was installed incorrectly. The trim is Collins TruWood. The siding is some sort of 3/8" panel (not overlapping), and appears to be the same material as Collins's composite fiber board trim. I can't find anything similar to the siding to patch in a fix. The closest I can get is non-residential rated siding: link
Any suggestions on a replacement? Picture attached for reference. The material in question is the white siding. The vertical white trim pieces are the Collins fiber board trim.

